# GrADS Code Error

Tags: grads

I am having trouble with this code in GrADS. The error kept saying that my two if statements were invalid. I reinstated some stars but it gave me a whole new error.

```
 "open NAM12Z0709.ctl"
 "set display color white"
 "clear"
 "set mpdset hires"
 "set grad off"
 "set lev 1000" 
 'run rgbset.gs'
 'set lat 36 38'
 'set lon -125 -120'
  'define lcl=((TMPsfc-DPT2m)*400)'
 'define tc=(TMPprs-273.15)'
 'define es=(6.11*exp((17.625*tc)/(tc+243.05)))'
 'define e=(es*RHprs/100)'
 'define wr=(622*e/(925-e))'
 'define expo=(exp((2257*wr)/(1004*TMPprs)))'
 'define numer=(-2.06327*TMPprs/(6516))'
 'define denom=(pow((RHprs/100),0.46))'
 'define thetae=(expo*numer/denom)'
 'define b=((-6.67*thetae-0.667)*(-0.1*VVELprs))'
  if (HGTprs <= lcl)
    'b=0'
  endif
  if (VVELprs >= 0)
    'b=0'
  endif
  'set clevs 0.0 0.125 0.25 0.375 0.5 0.625 0.75 0.875 1.0'
  'set ccols 1 4 13 3 10 7 12 8 2'
  'set gxout shaded'
  'set grads off'
  'd b'

  "printim testing12Zcloud.png png"
  'clear'
  'quit'
```

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing between Grads's variable/field and Grads Script's variable.
Specificlly, you cannot use HGTprs and VVELprs as a Grads script variable like that.